# Is $\mathrm{i}$ congruent $2$ or $3$ mod $5$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

The $5$-adic integers contain the $4$-th roots of unity $1$, $\mathrm{i}$, $-1$, and $-\mathrm{i}$. Solving the equations $x^2+1\equiv0\mod{5^k}$ gives two solutions: $\ldots3032431212$ and $\ldots1412013233$. Which of the two is $\mathrm{i}$ and which is $-\mathrm{i}$, if this question does even make sense?

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. There is no canonical way to distinguish $i$ from $-i$, neither in the complex numbers nor in the 5-adics.

Comment: Is there a preferred definition in the literature?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. There's no good reason to prefer either one to the other. Even solving $x^2+1\equiv0\bmod5$ gives two solutions, 2 and 3, and there's no reason to think one is a better $i$ than the other.